# Button adds input to form, but only first one. Not on multiple forms/divs

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm stuck here.

I have a 'working' function below (for each PHP array row, I"m creating a div with a form. The form has an empty input, a '+' button, and a submit button).

Using the first form/div, if I click the '+' button it adds an input field every time up to 10, which is exactly what I want.

However, when I do this on the 2nd, 3rd, or 4th form it adds inputs, but all of them to the first form. So if I click the '+' button on form 2, it adds an input to form 1. I know this has to do with having a non-unique button id and carrying that through my form inputs but I'm totally stuck on what to do here.

I need each form/div to have it's own independent fields, '+' button and submit button. Reason being, I'm going to add an AJAX call to the submit button that will submit any added input values for that given form (using the ticker ID given here `

```
`<?php echo $ticker['ticker'] ?>``) .
```

How can I fix this functionality to work for as many divs/forms as I have at any given time?

```
<div class="row">
    <?php foreach($tickerDisplays as $key => $ticker):?>
        <form id="Items" method="post">

                            <label id="ItemLabel">Item 1:</label>
                            <input type="text" name="Items[]"><br/>
                            <button type="button" class="moreItems_add" onclick="moreItems(this);">+</button>

                            <input type="hidden" name="tickerID" id="tickerID" value="<?php echo $ticker['ticker'] ?>">
                            <input type="submit" name="saveTickerItems" value="Save Ticker Items">  
                    </form>
    <?php endforeach;?>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">

var maxItems = 1;

function moreItems(button) {
  if (maxItems < 10) {
    var label = document.createElement("label");
    label.id="ItemLabel"+maxItems;
    label.innerHTML = "Item "+(maxItems+1)+": ";
    var input = document.createElement("input");
    input.type='text';
    input.name = 'item'+maxItems;

    $($(button).sibling('br')[0]).insertBefore($(button));
    $($(button).sibling('label')[0]).insertBefore($(button));
    $($(button).sibling('input:text')[0]).insertBefore($(button));
    maxItems++;
  }
}

</script>
```

[image]

Comment: It looks like you're constructing non-unique element ids

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tom, the id attribute for an HTML element needs to be unique, always make sure to use unique id's, if you want to do something for elements that are similar in most ways, use class, on a side note to solve your problem:

Also change your Html to this (pass the button into the function)
Also I changed your id to a class as moreItems_add and removed the id entirely:

```
<button type="button" class="moreItems_add" onclick="moreItems(this);">+</button>


//Accepts the button object
function moreItems(button) {
   //Instead of using a global iterator, grab the number of siblings of input type text
  const currentInputs = $(button).siblings('input:text').length;
  //Now use this variable to check if we hit the max of ten
  if(currentInputs < 10){}
```

replace these lines:

```
    $('<br/>').insertBefore("#moreItems_add");
    $(label).insertBefore("#moreItems_add");
    $(input).insertBefore("#moreItems_add");
```

with these lines:

```
    //$(button) refers to the button which was clicked
    //.siblings() will check the node structure for element(s) with the given selector on the same level as the button
    //pass the jquery object of the button which was clicked into insertBefore()
    //Pass the newly created object into the line of code before calling .siblings
     //These 2 are inserting the new label and input
     $($(label)).insertBefore($(button));
     $($(input)).insertBefore($(button));
     //Insert a line break so that the next label and input are on new line
     $('<br/>').insertBefore($(button));
```

Comment: I've just attempted this but it's not adding at all now

Comment: @TomN. I updated my answer, to a working example, since you are using inline events in your HTML, pass the button itself to your function, then use $(button) instead of $(this) to reference the button that was clicked

Comment: Ok so I tried that and plugged it in, you can see the full updated code above. Still no functionality though, not sure exactly what I'm missing

Comment: @TomN. I'm creating a JS Fiddle right now, one minute.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate your help

Comment: @TomN. I'm not being too bright today, I misspelled `.siblings()` as `.sibling()`, try it with my updated code snippet for the lines to replace, JSFiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/vj8ub5z9/24/)

Comment: So it's giving the alert, but it should be adding a new blank input on button click, Is this just attemptnig to add text?

Comment: Nevermind, i think it's alerting every time where It would be adding the input right?

Comment: @TomN. I updated the fiddle to remove the alert message and debugger stuff (https://jsfiddle.net/vj8ub5z9/26/), I'm not sure if the fiddle is exactly as you want as the HTML was not constructed completely since you are doing that through some php code which I was not able to replicate in the fiddle

Comment: But it still just creates a space before the input. The code I started my question with was adding a blank input below the existing input on each button press. The functionality worked just not for multiple forms though. I may have lost something in translation though, as far as what this should be doing

Comment: sorry, check my update with images to make more sense of it

Comment: @TomN. Created a new working fiddle which should give you what you want: (https://jsfiddle.net/vj8ub5z9/49/), please see updated answer.

Comment: I just added this and the functionality is fixed .However, look at my screenshot in my question: THey're adding to each form, but it's keeping the same iterator. BY no means do you have to help any further, as I'm accepting your answer now regardless. But do you know off hand if there's a better way for me to iterate?

Comment: @TomN. Added to my answer for you, to show you how you would use the passed in button to get the current number of inputs of type text that are siblings of the button, this will replace the use of a global iterator variable. Thanks for the reputation and happy coding.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use the same ID to reference different DOM elements, use classes or an ID with a postfix.

Comment: I actually attempted this using a class, but then when I click any of the '+' buttons it adds to all of them instead of just the first one

Comment: Just because you need to refactor your code allowing the button to recognize the correct form, you can, for example, add a click event to the button and search for the parent form or set an unique ID and pass it to moreItems() as a variable

Comment: Well, the function is currently being called with an onclick event coming from the button

Comment: Yep, i mean, if you use $(your_button).on('click', function() {}); it's more usable, then you can simply do $(this).closest('your_form').whatevereyouhavetodo

Answer (score 1):

If you are calling the JavaScript function to apply to a specific form you should instead call a function with a class name that applies to all of your forms. Instead of using an ID use a class

Answer (score 1):

The  ids have to be unique. How about if you "build them" by appending ticket number?.
Something like
 `id="<? php echo ("Items".$ticket) ?>"`. Then you can get the element's id in the js, and `insertBefore` as appropriate.

For the button, it would be something like this:
`<button type="button" id="<?php echo "moreItems_add".$ticker ?>" onclick="moreItems(this);">+</button>`

Similarly for the form element:
`<form id="<?php echo "Items".$ticker ?>" method="post">`

This will give each form element and each button element a unique id. --**edit**->- The idea being you could use that id in the js instead of `#moreItems_add` here`'<br/>').insertBefore("#moreItems_add");` (from the original iteration of the post). That said, I hadn't groked that no object was being sent to the function (ie this here  `moreItems(this);` and button here `function moreItems(button)`. (And on top of all that, jquery is, ahem, not my best thing). The bottom line is: if you need an unique id for the button in the javascript, you will find it now at `button.id`.

Comment: Sorry, can you structure that into a small example?

Comment: added info to the answer. I hope it's what you need :)

Comment: I see, thanks! Now how would I pass these in the JS though?